# How to customize StormCrawler?

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

Although I have been working with Apache Storm for a while, I am fairly new to StormCrawler.

I started a project from the StormCrawler+ES archetype. However, to customize StormCrawler, at what specific point should additional bolts be added?

Dave.

Comment: Hi Dave, it depends what you need to do which isn't done of the box. You don't HAVE to add new bolts, the ones set by default might be sufficient. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Hi Julien. Thanks for your reply! I want to identify images using web crawling, and process these further. When a webserver provides a response, I want to identify whether the response is/contains an image, and if so, extract information about that image and store it in ElasticSearch. This use case can maybe best described as a service that allows people to upload their image to my server, and that the service checks whether this image has been used elsewhere. E.g., because of protecting copyright.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing would be to write a custom bolt and add it between the fetcher and the parser. It should look at the metadata for any mimetype given in the http response (bearing in mind the prefix used to store the [info from the protocol](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/pull/789)), possibly detecting the mimetype as done in the [JSOUPParser](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/bolt/JSoupParserBolt.java#L172). If it is an image then do your specific processing for it, then emit to the output. If it isn't, emit to a custom stream; the latter would be connected to the JSOUP parser so that you get outlinks; the former goes into ES.

You can find examples of dealing with the non-defaults streams in various places, in particular, the [Tika module](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/tika).